# How to sort array that has nested objects with ISO date

Tags: javascript

```
  const info = [{
                    "userID" : "aaa",
                    "dob" : "2021-07-23 22:30:00.000Z" <--- String
                }, 
                {
                    "userID" : "aaa11",
                    "dob" : "2021-06-10 12:30:00.000Z" <--- String
                }, 
                {
                    "userID" : "aaa22",
                    "dob" : "2021-09-23 22:30:00.000Z" <--- String
                }]
```

I've been using sort to rearrange the list. However, I am quite stuck, sorting with the string.

`info.sort((a, b) => a.dob - b.dob);`

This works with the number but does not work with the string. I've been trying to look for the answer here, however, I could not figure it out how to sort with the `ISO date` string. How can I do this?

Comment: `a.dob > b.dob ? 1 : (a.dob == b.dob ? 0 : -1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date) as follows:

```js
const info = [ { "userID" : "aaa", "dob" : "2021-07-23 22:30:00.000Z" }, { "userID" : "aaa11", "dob" : "2021-06-10 12:30:00.000Z" }, { "userID" : "aaa22", "dob" : "2021-09-23 22:30:00.000Z" } ];

const sorted = info.sort(({ dob: a }, { dob: b }) => new Date(a) - new Date(b));

console.log(sorted);
```

Another way using [`String#localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare):

```js
const info = [ { "userID" : "aaa", "dob" : "2021-07-23 22:30:00.000Z" }, { "userID" : "aaa11", "dob" : "2021-06-10 12:30:00.000Z" }, { "userID" : "aaa22", "dob" : "2021-09-23 22:30:00.000Z" } ];

const sorted = info.sort(({ dob: a }, { dob: b }) => a.localeCompare(b));

console.log(sorted);
```

Comment: Pretty much the same as the accepted answer on the duplicate, especially after the edit, which came after I added the potential duplicate...

Comment: I was applying it on `MongoDB` `$function`, that was why, `new Date()` did not work. However, this has worked as expected! Thank you so much mate.